# Integrating HTMX with Google reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, htmx

I have a basic HTMX form, that I want to integrate with Google reCaptcha (v3) so that when the user clicks the submit button, some JavaScript will call the reCaptcha API to obtain a token, which is then added to a hidden field which the back end can pick-up.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="form" hx-post="/page" hx-target="#content">
    <input id="recaptcha-token" type="hidden" name="ReCaptchaToken" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Initially I was thinking of hooking into the `htmx:configRequest` event to modify the parameters sent in the request like so:

```
<script>
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (e) => {
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
            e.detail.parameters.ReCaptchaToken = token;
          });
        });
    });   
 </script>
```

But of course this doesn't work because of async nature of `execute` - i.e. the event handler finishes before resolving the execute promise.

How can I integrate the reCaptcha call before the HTMX form post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the recaptcha callback dispatch an event when it's done, then set hx-trigger to listen for it.

```
<form id="my-form" hx-post="/endpoint" hx-target=".container" hx-trigger="verified">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <button type="submit" data-sitekey="your-key" data-callback="announce">Submit</button>
</form>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script>
function announce(){
    const event = new Event('verified');
    const elem = document.querySelector("#my-form");
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}
</script>
```